# fasterxml JSON serialization: how to set a certain order of fields?

Tags: json, serialization, fasterxml

Is there any way to impose certain order of fields for FasterXML JSON serialization?
For example, I need myObject.date go exactly first, then myObject.amount exactly after that, then myObject.itemsCollection, etc.

If there is no existing method to do it, then how can I implement it?
I think about using some custom annotations for the object fields but I don't know where to start, what to do next...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple. Just use this annotation in the class to be serialized: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html